# Align along \dots in multi-language table

Tags: tables, horizontal-alignment, polyglossia, hebrew, ellipsis

I would like each of the two columns to align along the `\dots`. It's unclear to me if a `siunitx`-based solution is appropriate here.

```
%XeLaTeX
\documentclass[11pt]{scrbook}

\usepackage{libertine}
\usepackage{microtype}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
    \setdefaultlanguage{english}
    \setotherlanguage{hebrew}
    \newfontfamily\hebrewfont[Script=Hebrew]{Linux Libertine O}
    \newfontfamily\englishfont[Ligatures=NoCommon]{Linux Libertine O}

\begin{document}

    \begin{tabular}{lr} \toprule
\multicolumn{2}{c}{Table Title} \\ 
\midrule
e/a\dots{} & \begin{Large}\texthebrew{א\dots}\end{Large}\\
t\dots{} & \begin{Large}\texthebrew{ת\dots}\end{Large} \\
t\dots{} & \begin{Large}\texthebrew{ת\dots{}י}\end{Large} \\
y\dots{} & \begin{Large}\texthebrew{י\dots{}}\end{Large} \\
t\dots{} & \begin{Large}\texthebrew{ת\dots{}}\end{Large} \\
\cmidrule(lr){1-2}
n\dots{} & \begin{Large}\texthebrew{נ\dots{}}\end{Large} \\
t\dots{}u & \begin{Large}\texthebrew{ת\dots{}ו}\end{Large} \\
y\dots{}u & \begin{Large}\texthebrew{י\dots{}ו}\end{Large} \\
\bottomrule
    \end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could switch from a 2-column to a 4-column layout. The separator between columns 1 and 2 and between columns 3 and 4 can be set to `@{\dots}`. (If the `array` package is loaded, `@{\dots}` means "replace the normal intercolumn whitespace with `\dots`".) Next, make columns 1 and 3 right-aligned and columns 2 and 4 left-aligned. Finally, add `>{\Large}` prefix directives to columns 3 and 4.

[image]

```
% !TEX TS-program = xelatex
\documentclass[11pt]{scrbook}
\usepackage{array} % <-- new
\usepackage{libertine}
\usepackage{microtype}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setdefaultlanguage{english}
\setotherlanguage{hebrew}
\newfontfamily\hebrewfont[Script=Hebrew]{Linux Libertine O}
\newfontfamily\englishfont[Ligatures=NoCommon]{Linux Libertine O}

\begin{document}

\noindent
\begin{tabular}{@{} r @{\dots} l @{\qquad} 
           >{\Large}r @{\dots} >{\Large}l @{}} 
\toprule
\multicolumn{4}{c}{Table Title} \\ 
\midrule
e/a& &                &\texthebrew{א} \\
t&   &                &\texthebrew{ת} \\
t&   & \texthebrew{י} &\texthebrew{ת} \\
y&   &                &\texthebrew{י} \\
t&   &                &\texthebrew{ת} \\
\midrule
n&   &                &\texthebrew{נ} \\
t&u  & \texthebrew{ו} &\texthebrew{ת}\\
y&u  & \texthebrew{ו} &\texthebrew{י}\\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Just in case it isn't clear: If you think the amount of whitespace between columns 1/2 and 3/4 is too large, just change `@{\qquad}` to, say, `@{\quad}`.

Comment: How can I use your code with `n` columns?

Comment: @minhthien_2016 - Sure. (I assume you mean `n` *pairs* of columns, right?)

Comment: I mean, e.g, A ... B ... C (3 columns).

Comment: @minhthien_2016 - I'm very sorry, but I simply don't understand your follow-up question. E.g., where or how do "A", "B", and "C" come into the picture? I also don't understand the relationship between your follow-up question and the question posted by the OP. If you have a new question, please post a new query.